# mysql having and where clause on the same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

This is the code I have :

```
$sqlz = "SELECT t1.user_id, t2.status, t2.email 
         FROM coverages t1 
         LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
         GROUP BY t1.user_id  
         HAVING COUNT(t1.user_id) =".$value;
```

I would like to add this "`WHERE users.email IS NOT NULL`"
When I do add it, it returns a white page /  no results. which I know for a fact there are at least 200 results on the db that contain an email and and match that criteria.

this is an example of what I did that did not work:

```
 $sqlz =    "SELECT t1.user_id, t2.status, t2.email 
             FROM coverages t1 
             LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
             WHERE users.email IS NOT NULL 
             GROUP BY t1.user_id  
             HAVING COUNT(t1.user_id) =".$value;
```

Comment: You have given your `users` table the alias `t2`: you will therefore need to use that alias in your `WHERE` criterion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you need to use `t2` (*alias*) instead of `users`.

```
 $sqlz =    "SELECT t1.user_id, t2.status, t2.email 
             FROM coverages t1 
                     LEFT JOIN users t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
             WHERE t2.email IS NOT NULL 
             GROUP BY t1.user_id  
             HAVING COUNT(t1.user_id) = " .$value;
```

Comment: having clause works but if i add it in where it wont work. May i know the secret behind this?